# How to tell if node.js is installed or not

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've recently installed node.js and I have no idea how to run applications. I installed node.js but couldn't find further instructions. What does one really need to do? I wanted to see if it was actually working. So I executed a script called hello.js. It went as such:

```
console.log('hello world');
```

Now where would this be logged to?

**Edit**

I'm running this .js through a .php script.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using Windows and I open `cmd`, node is in the system path so if you type `node -v` you should see the version. Mine is 0.6.15. Running `node hello.js`, the console.log just prints to the command prompt. In Mac and Linux I think you would just use the terminal and do the above.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to mention that a php script is executing this.

Comment: I got confused by the word "terminal". For naive users like me, it is nothing but "command prompt" in windows machines. Run -> Type cmd -> Command Prompt windows appear -> type `node --version`. You should see version number.

Comment: Btw it ain't "dumbies" it's dummies

Answer (score 236):

Open a terminal window.
Type:

```
node -v
```

This will display your `nodejs` version.

Navigate to where you saved your script and input:

```
node script.js
```

This will run your script.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to mention I am running this through a php script. So where then will it be printed if not by terminal?

Comment: @user1340052, `exec()` returns the last line from the output, so you should be fine there.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: For node and command line newbies, like me who just wasted an hour at node blogs, the phrase "open a terminal window" means do 1 of 2 things in Windows. Either use the Start button, go to Accessories, click Command Prompt;  or in the Start button, go to All Programs, then the Node directory, then Node.js Command Prompt. Node has changed and a lot of blogs are way out of date, or just plain obscure about Windows. Hope this saves you an hour.

Comment: how can I know if I have a 32-bit or a 64-bit ?

Comment: Your OS is either 32-bit or 64-bit.  When you install nodejs it picks the matching version.

Comment: It might be that the node is installed but it is not in your path (win env/bash/zsh)

Comment: "node script.js" is showing error in my cmd;

Answer (score 21):

open a terminal and enter

```
node -v
```

this will tell you the version of the nodejs installed, then run nodejs simple by entering

```
node
```

Prompt must be change. Enter following,

```
function testNode() {return "Node is working"}; testNode();
```

command line must prompt the following output if the installation was successful

```
'Node is working'
```

Answer (score 13):

Check the node version by typing in your terminal

```
node -v
```

Check the npm version by typing

```
npm -v
```

If these commands give you the version numbers for `node` and `npm` you are good to go with `NodeJs` development

---

**Time to test node**

Create a Directory by running the command.

```
mkdir NodeJs
```

Change your directory to the `NodeJs` folder and create a file

```
touch index.js
```

Open your `index.js` either using `vi` or in your favorite text editor.

Type in

```
console.log('Welcome to NodesJs.')
```

and save the file.

Navigate back to your saved file in the terminal and type

```
node index.js
```

If you see `Welcome to NodesJs.` you did a nice job and you are up with NodeJs.

Answer (score 11):

(This is for windows OS but concept can be applied to other OS)

Running command `node -v` will be able to confirm if it is installed, however it will not be able to confirm if it is NOT installed. (Executable may not be on your PATH)

Two ways you can check if it is actually installed:

1. Check default install location `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`

or

2. Go to `System Settings -> Add or Remove Programs` and filter by `node`, it should show you if you have it installed. For me, it shows as title:"Node.js" and description "Node.js Foundation", with no version specified. Install size is 52.6MB

If you don't have it installed, get it from here https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: When I type node -v, a prompt opens and closes quickly. Node is def installed but based on other answers I'm expecting to be able to read something. How do I keep the prompt open?

Comment: @wazz That definitely shouldn't happen, perhaps your install is corrupted some how? Are you using windows? If so use control panel to uninstall, and then reinstall stable version

Comment: major facepalm. i didn't open cmd. i just typed into the 'run' dialog...tnx.

Comment: could someone tell me the windows command to see the folder that node is installed in? The equivalent command of "which node" on Mac

Answer (score 9):

Please try this command **node --version** or **node -v**, either of which should return something like `v4.4.5`.

Comment: I have nodejs 5.6.0 installed and running "nodejs -version" through terminal returned "command not found". "node -v" is the correct command.

Comment: @markp3rry did you run "nodejs -version" or "nodejs --version" (note the double dash)

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> - to open the command line 
and then writes:

```
node -v
```

Answer (score 3):

Open the command prompt in Windows or terminal in Linux and Mac.Type

```
node -v
```

If node is install it will show its version.For eg.,

```
v6.9.5
```

Else download it from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, there was a problem with the installation, so I got the .msi file for windows, the installer I meant, run it, but clicked on repair instead