# How to tell how node was installed?

Tags: node.js

I may need to reinstall some js libraries, starting with node.

I know [node is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475651/how-to-tell-if-node-js-is-installed-or-not/10475672) since `node -v` returns `v16.0.0`. But I don't know what I used to install it (e.g. npm, homebrew, yarn etc).

How can I find this out?

#### Notes

```
which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

```
brew list node
/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0/bin/node
/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0/etc/bash_completion.d/npm
/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0/include/node/ (17 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0/lib/dtrace/node.d
/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0/libexec/bin/ (2 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0/libexec/lib/ (2752 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0/share/doc/ (2 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0/share/man/man1/node.1
/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
```

```
npm list node
zsh: command not found: npm
```

Comment: One way to look into your terminal history and check for node install commands that you used.

Comment: @wrangler thanks very much for the suggestion. I just checked `~/.zsh_history` but unfortunately it doesn't go back far enough. Appreciate the suggestion all the same

Comment: Why does it matters how it was installed?

Comment: @Alejandro I once nonchalantly attempted to install ruby with rvm when I'd previously installed it with rbenv, and the ensuing mess took me 2 weeks to clean up. I don't want to make a similar mistake with node. If making a mess is impossible, please let me know, I haven't used enough of any js package managers to know.

Answer (score 2):

`which node` will tell you *where* node is installed. This might help you figure it out if you know X installer installs at a specific installation.

`npm list node` and `npm list -g node` should rule out whether or not your installation comes from npm.

Similarly, `brew list node` will only list Node versions installed with homebrew. (Note that you might have node installed via homebrew at a certain location different than what `which node` returned, meaning you did many installations.)

As for `n` and `nvm`, if they're installed, I'd try changing node version from those utilities. If doing so changes the output of `node -v`, then node must be installed from those.

Comment: Thanks, I'll include the output of these commands in my question (would place them here, but they'll get messy in the comments)

Comment: Since `brew list node` returns some results, does that mean I installed it with brew?

Comment: If it means I installed it with homebrew, I [probably shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63511950/5783745)

Comment: humm yeah maybe. I've been happily using n (https://github.com/tj/n) for the past few years and it worked great for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a UNIX-based operating system there is a history command that will show you the commands previously executed in the terminal as `wrangler` commented. If you're using Ubuntu you can find the log history for `apt-get` in `/var/log/apt/history`. These utilities (`npm`, `homebrew`, `yarn`, `apt-get`, etc.) all have logs that you can look through. If you're using Windows you probably downloaded node directly from their site.